# Moving Lucene index to another server

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I am in the process of moving my Lucene indexing offline to be done by a conusmer of a JMS queue. I have it all working as it should. It creates the index correctly and I'm able to rsync the index files to the new box. The question is what is the best approach to have Lucene use the new index? How are others reinitializing their IndexWriters to use the new index files?
Thanks!

Comment: I am supposing you have all files that are indexed in new box, right?

Comment: Why can't you just open the index normally? (What other options are there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who come after me, here is what I've done.

The goal was to have my JMS consumer generate my lucene index and then have each of my servers pull that new index when it's complete. 
Here are the steps I took:

- Created a crontab to generate my new index nightly
- Created a crontab to call a script updateLuceneIndex.sh to update the new index on each server

## !/bin/sh

TIME=`date +%s`;
rsync -av tomcat@consumer1.***.com:/home/tomcat/lucene /home/tomcat/lucene
echo $TIME
mv -f /home/tomcat/lucene/lucene /home/tomcat/lucene/$TIME

As you see above it uses the timestamp as the directory name so the new index will show up in a folder named like

```
/home/tomcat/lucene/1300291879
```

- The server code will grab a list of the directories in the /home/tomcat/lucene directory.
- It sorts them based on the name of the new directory and grabs the last one (the newest)
- The server than deletes all old indexes except for the last 2 (in case one is corrupt)
- I create a new IndexReader pointing to the new directory

I'm not sure if this is thread safe. I imagine if someone tries to search right when I am switching they'll get an error but I currently don't have that many searches to make that a likely scenario. However, as our traffic grows it will definitely be a spot where things could break. If anyone knows a better way please advise.

Here's that code:

```
public void initialize(File newIndexDirectory) throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
        try {
            File path = (newIndexDirectory == null) ? new File(indexDirectory) : newIndexDirectory;
            Directory index = new SimpleFSDirectory(path);
            searcher = new IndexSearcher(index);
            logger.debug("Successfully initialized index at: " + path.getAbsolutePath());
            currentIndexFile = path;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Lucene index is corrupt");
        }
    }
```